# Car is not smooth after a engine tune up

Tags: acceleration, fuel-injection, maruti, alto

I have a 2010 Indian Alto 800 car (124530 kms). Few months ago car started to accelerate it self when stationary. Then I sprayed a carburetor cleaner through the air intake and i was able to fix the issue temporally.

I went to the mechanic and they cleaned the carburetor, replaced air filter, reset the EFI and plugs. Also changed the fuel filter as well.

Now it works fine. Check engine is not showing anymore and It can do around 19 - 22 km/l with even AC on. The idle rpm is good ( There's no rpm meter in this car so by sound I feel like it is good and not so high. )

However now the car is not smooth when driving. Specially when driving in 1, 2 and 3rd gears. There are 3 main scenarios.

**Gear shifting**

Suppose I have to suddenly downshift from 3rd to 1st and then drive on 1st gear. When I do this it takes more time by the engine to reduce the rpm and so it is almost impossible to shift from 3rd to 1st without slow down to 0 and wait for like 2 - 3 seconds to let engine to slow down before release clutch. If I do release the clutch around 5kmph the car pulls back and I can feel the pressure on the clutch. In few cases I felt the clutch slipped. The thing is the clutch and pressure plates are replaced recently.

Also, before the engine tune up, I was able to shift from 2nd to 3rd smoothly around 40 - 50kmph. But now I have to shift from 2nd to 3rd around 20 - 25kmph if I want to make it a smooth engagement. Otherwise the car will always pulls back when releasing the clutch and puts more pressure on clutch.

**Driving down hill on 3rd or 2nd gear**

Suppose I drive downhill ( Not a sharp one ) on 3rd gear without using accelerator. It feels like I am driving on the gear with engine turned off ( Feels like too much engine break )

**Driving in Traffic**

When I drive in a high traffic area around 5 - 20kmph the car does not feel smooth at all and it is impossible to engage clutch smoothly. Also say I drive around 10kmph in the traffic without pressing the clutch and I try to accelerate to increase speed. When I try to do this car jumps no matter how slow I press the accelerator. It feels like the engine is responding to the accelerator with some kind of delay. So to prevent this jumping I have to always press clutch and release it slowly. This was not an issue before the tune up.

---

Driving on 4th and 5th gear feels okay and both upshift and downshift work smoothly in these gears.

I would really appreciate any help to locate the problem.

Thanks.